# enumerating localStorage properties

Tags: javascript

i would  like to enumerate the local Storage properties not including its methods and length field.
Alas I don't know how. 
I use

```
for (var key in localStorage)
    a.push([key, localStorage[key] ]);
```

The interesting thing is : on an old  machine this very code worked fine. now on my good machine its also enumerates functions and length thereby smashing my code and making sad and angry :(

Comment: you should not use unfiltered for loops on objects with inherited methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    a.push([key, localStorage[key]]);
}
```

instead of that `for in` enumeration. Although I find it hard to believe that those methods and `length` are enumerable

Comment: Actually [I didn't have problem in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/hsw32zv8/2/). The OP code and yours gave the same results, that's interesting.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: What browser are you using? When I tested your fiddle, the `for in`-enumeration gave the items *plus* the methods in Opera 12, while the loop gave the expected results.

Comment: I'm using chrome. Although Firefox gives even more completely different results (`key`,`getItem`,`setItem`, ... ) for the `for in` and proper results for the `for`.